# sql sum of date differences

Tags: android, sql, sql-server, database, sqlite

i am developing an android application which has a table named "entries"
the table structure is as follows

```
id     name      operation       date
----------------------------------------------
1     engine        on        08-03-2015 19.22
2     engine        off       08-03-2015 19.23
3     light         on        08-03-2015 19.23
4     light         off       08-03-2015 19.28
5     engine        on        08-03-2015 19.28
6     engine        off       08-03-2015 19.30
```

i woul like to get the output as follows

```
name    duration
----------------
engine  3
light   5
```

That is the total time on which the engine and light if in on state.
In detail for engine the time difference b/w on and off state are added and taken as output.similarly for light.
Anyone plz help me
Dont know how to start.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or SQLite?

Comment: i am using sqlite android database

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using ANSI SQL (compatible with both SQL Server and SQLite) by using a correlated subquery to get the "off" value for each on:

```
select name,
       sum(strftime('%s', offtime) - strftime('%s', date)) as numseconds
from (select e.*,
             (select min(e2.date)
              from entries e2
              where e2.name = e.name and
                    e2.date > e.date and
                    e.operation = 'off'
             ) as offtime
      from entries e
      where operation = 'on'
     ) e
group by name;
```

Note that this uses the SQLite construct for calculating the duration in seconds.  There is a similar construct in SQL Server using `datediff()`.

EDIT:

In SQL Server:

```
select name,
       datediff(seconds, date, offtime) as numseconds
from (select e.*,
             (select min(e2.date)
              from entries e2
              where e2.name = e.name and
                    e2.date > e.date and
                    e.operation = 'off'
             ) as offtime
      from entries e
      where operation = 'on'
     ) e
group by name;
```

Comment: iam getting following error    Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 2
'strftime' is not a recognized built-in function name.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'off'.

Comment: `strftime()` is a rather integral part of SQLite:  https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html.  It is rather suspicious, though, that your error message is a SQL Server error message.

Comment: thanks gordon let me try in sqlite and will let you know the result

Comment: it shows error on sqlite as       [ no such column: off ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]